# Add selected from join table fields in Entity, Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-query

When I run:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('debtor')
->join('debtor.deals', 'deal')
->addSelect('...something... as closed_deals_count')
->getQuery()
->getSingleResult()
```

It results in the following structure:

```
array:3 [
    0 => Debtor {...},
    'closed_deals_count' => 0
]
```

How could I get a single Debtor record with 'closed_deals_count' in it instead of an array?

Comment: you can't push it inside that array, but you can use extra select field in your query for example in orderby and hide it in result.

Comment: Doctrine 2 does not handle "virtual columns" like what you want out of the box.  You can write your own custom hydrator: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes But it might be overkill.  I would just add a line of code and merge the data myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `getSingleScalarResult`. Something like:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('debtor')
->join('debtor.deals', 'deal')
->addSelect('COUNT(deal.id) as closed_deals_count')
->getQuery()
->getSingleScalarResult()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This code return only one number, but I want to get Entity which includes closed_deals_count.

Comment: That's what you are getting in your question right? An array of Debtor entities with closed_deals_count attached. What are you after, exactly?

Comment: He is actually getting an array containing a debtor entity as well as the closed_deals_count.  What he wants is a debtor entity with the closed_deals_count as a property.  Somethi9ng which will take a bit more code.